# GridSearchCV Not Showing Verbose Levels

Tags: python, machine-learning, gridsearchcv

The **Verbose** arguement in the **GridSearchCV** function displays the processing steps for each execution. Las time when I used, it worked just fine. But when I ran the model today, the verbose steps are not displaying. I didn't change my code at all. It's just the same.

```
model_gbm_sk = GradientBoostingClassifier(random_state = 0)
params_gbm = {'learning_rate':[0.05,0.1,0.2,0.3], 'n_estimators':[50,100], 'max_depth':[3,6,9,None]}
grid_gbm_sk = GridSearchCV(model_gbm_sk, params_gbm, scoring = 'accuracy', cv = 5, verbose = 5, n_jobs = -1, return_train_score = True)
grid_gbm_sk.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

for which the output displayed was `Fitting 5 folds for each of 32 candidates, totalling 160 fits` and nothing else after that. What's worse, the time for execution increased a lot than before. I only updated the version of **scikit-learn** via the pip command. Is this happening due to updating the version, or is there any other reason?

Comment: Could you try `verbose = 10`? Also are you using a GPU for training?

Comment: How to check whether GPU is used or not?

Comment: If you are using a Jupyter notebook run `!nvidia-smi`.

Comment: ```'nvidia-smi' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the new version of **Scikit-learn** (0.24.1). When I reverted to the previous version (0.23.2) and ran the model again, it is working just fine like how it used to work. So my suggestion is not to use the latest version of sklearn (0.24.0 and 0.24.1) and continue with the version 0.23.2. This way, our models will run soon.

`pip install scikit-learn==0.23.2`

Comment: I'm sure this is something the sklearn devs would want to know about.  Please raise an Issue on their github page.  (I was under the impression that verbosity didn't work too well with `n_jobs!=1`, but perhaps I'm misremembering.  But the slower runtime is surely an undesirable regression.)